# 3D graphing the parameter space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, 3d, sagemath

[3D parameter space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxOT3.jpg)Hi there I was given the equation X'= [a,b
c,0]X and was asked to graph the parameter space as "a" changes. I tried but I'm not completely sure this is what they were looking for. I put the equation 4D-T^2<0 or 4(Determinant)-(Trace)^2 < 0, into the graph then sectioned off the quadrants where D is positive and negative. I understand how the system changes with the fluctuation of "a" when looking at the bc-plane but I can't really conceptualize 3D. Is it just adding "a" as an axis? and if so how do I code that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean differential system $\pmatrix{x'\\y'}=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&0}\pmatrix{x\\y}$ ? Latex form for this expression : `$\pmatrix{x'\\y'}=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&0}\pmatrix{x\\y}$`

Comment: You mention "sagemath" : could you give your program ?